# TestCafe: The TypeText function seems to use CAPS LOCK for UpperCase letters. Is there a way to tell it to use SHIFT instead?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

We have a test that types text into a password field and on our website we indicate a warning to the end user when their CAPS LOCK key is on. We've noticed that passwords which end in an uppercase letter are causing our tests to fail because we don't expect the CAPS LOCK error to be displayed at this time.

Does anyone know if there is a way to tell ".typeText" to use the SHIFT key instead of CAPS LOCK? Or are there alternative ways to enter this text such that the caps lock key won't be used?  (I suppose we could send the 'CTRL+V' key combo, but we are hoping not to use that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`t.typeText()`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/typetext.html#options) has all sorts of options you can specify.

```js
await t
    .typeText(nameInput, 'text', { paste: true });
```

This will input the text as one keystroke (similar to copy & paste). It might help you. Or you can play with modifiers object within options.